# How can I set the value for each default key in different subdirectories of regedit?

Tags: powershell, python, cmd.exe, windows-registry, java

Here is a screenshot what I'm working with:

[screenshot of regedit directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CS4gE.png)

I wanna run a script that will set every default key in each subdirectory named mplayerc64.*\shell to "enqueue" (no quotes)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerShell:

```
Get-ChildItem Registry::HKCR\mplayerc64.* -Recurse |
  Where PSChildName -eq 'Shell' |
Set-ItemProperty -Name '(Default)' -Value 'enqueue'
```

Aliased:

```
gci Registry::HKCR\mplayerc64.* -s | ? PSChildName -eq 'Shell' | sp -Name '(Default)' -Value 'enqueue'
```

Comment: this is exactly what i'm looking for but something's wrong and i don't know how to fix it. i'm not getting an error but the script never ends. i tried both the powershell and aliased versions. i ran each version as a user and admin, and then ran them all over again with a lowercase 'shell' to match the directory string exactly--same result every time, it doesn't finish, and i don't even know where to begin

Comment: this works fine. i wrote the question wrong, the directory is actually "mplayerc64*" thank you!

Comment: Cool. Thanks for marking my replay as 'Answer'. So no period in the key name, right? For the sake of future readers, I'll edit the question and answer....

Comment: no problem. the period is still there i'm just sloppy , your edit is correct

Comment: I figured it out after a second look & checking the original screen shot!

Answer (score 0):

1. Export the Registry key and subkeys as one .reg file, e.g., *no_def.reg*.
2. Open in the.reg file in a text editor, such as *Notepad* or *Notepad++*.
3. Manually, or by search-and-replace, insert `@="enqueue" after each key.
4. Check **carefully** for errors --  a mistake in a *Registry* entry can cause immense problems.
5. Save the .reg file under a differe4nt name, *enq.reg*.

Now you can apply the new .reg file, see if it works as needed, and can revert to the original settings using the first (unmodified) exported file.

**N.B.** Massive Registry changes can cause issues. Make a disk image, to be safe, before making these changes.